# JavaScript ES6 Module basic question: .mjs file extension and MIME type

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm experiencing what I hope is a trivial issue with ES6 modules:

- If I use a .mjs file extension for a JavaScript module, browsers such as Chrome and Firefox are happy - but if I use .js, I get error messages.
- BUT, the very simpleminded server that I need to use (it's a specialized embedded server), serves up .mjs files with a MIME type of plain text, rather than as JavaScript.

Here's a simple example:

Default.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="/ModuleTest/modScript.js" type="module"></script>;
<script src="/ModuleTest/moduleTest.js" type="module"></script>;
<title>Module Test</title>
</head>
    
<body>
<script  type="text/JavaScript">
    document.getElementById("field1").innerHTML = square(33);
    
</script>
    
<div class="textField" id="field1">xxx</div>                                                     

</body>
</html>
```

And moduleTest.mjs:

```js
// JavaScript Document
'use strict';
'sourceType: module';

export function square (x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

Here, if I use a file extension of .js (moduleTest.js), I get error messages like:

```
ERROR: Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear with 'sourceType: module'
```

I seem to be stuck. The modules are only treated as modules by the browser if they have an .mjs file extension ... BUT .mjs files are served up as plain text files, and I get MIME errors from the server.

This seems like the kind of basic question that Mr. Google should be able to answer in a few minutes - but multiple readings of my JavaScript books, and a multitude of searches have failed to yield a solution.

Getting .js files to actually be parsed as modules seems to be the only option, since I have no control over the idiot server. I don't understand why specifying

```html
<script src="/ModuleTest/moduleTest.js" type="module"></script>;
```

doesn't do the trick.

The runtime error I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: square is not defined
  at default.html: 12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oops - "doesn't do the trick" should have read: <script src="/ModuleTest/moduleTest.js" type="module"></script>; doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Is the `Parsing error: 'import' and 'export..` error caused by the browser or by ESLint in your code editor?

Comment: If you want to use an exported function or value, then you should import into a module. Otherwise the scripts would just be globally available and `import` / `export` wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! The Parsing error is produced by both ESLint (using DreamWeaver), and by the browser if I serve up the JavaScript file.  Certainly the purpose of modules is to control the namespace: this is just a trivial example - but ultimately I am expecting to be able to call a function that a module exports from Javascript that is local to an HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what is happening here is that your module is not exporting `square` ***to*** anything. Exports like that only work when you import them into another script.

For example, if you import the script into another module (keep in mind that you cannot import local modules in a web page) then you can use it:

```js
//File: /ModuleTest/modScript.js
'use strict';
'sourceType: module';

export function square (x) {
    return x * x;
}

//File: /ModuleTest/impScript.js
'use strict';
'sourceType: module';

import { square } from "./modScript";

console.log(square(2)); //4
```

Now, imported variables are (at least in my experience and all of my failures to do this) are not added to the window. For example, if I had this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head />
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import { Octokit } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/octokit";
      console.log("From import:", Octokit) // class extends this { ... }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log(Octokit) //Uncaught ReferenceError: Octokit is not defined
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("From window:", window.Octokit) //undefined
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Octokit variable is only avaliable in the `type="module"` script, and it is loaded after the rest of the scripts.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought that it was not permissible for scripts that are contained in an HTML file to be declared as modules. However, when I tried it like this, it miraculously worked!
``` 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="/ModuleTest/moduleTest.js" type="module"></script>;
<title>Module Test</title>
</head>
 
<body>
<script  type="module">
 import {square} from "/ModuleTest/ModuleTest.js";
 document.getElementById("field1").innerHTML = square(33);
 
</script>
 
<div class="textField" id="field1">xxx</div>              

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem. I went down the exact same rabbit hole myself a little while back.

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted code block -  I have not figured out how to flag part of a comment as code in StackOverflow  :(

Comment: In the bar on top there is a little button that looks like a little paper with a `<>` on it. Press that, insert your code, and press "Save & Insert Into Post"

Comment: Thanks!    ---     Again!